# Overloaded method value createDirectStream in error Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

When making the call

```
val kafkaParams: Map[String, String] =...
var topic: String = ..
val input2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topic.toSet)
```

I get the error:

> overloaded method value createDirectStream with alternatives: (jssc:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,keyClass:
>   Class[String],valueClass: Class[String],keyDecoderClass:
>   Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder],valueDecoderClass:
>   Class[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder],kafkaParams:
>   java.util.Map[String,String],topics:
>   java.util.Set[String])org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream[String,String]
>    (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,kafkaParams:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String],topics:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Set[String])(implicit evidence$19:
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$20:
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$21:
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder], implicit
>   evidence$22:
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.StringDecoder])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(String,
>   String)] cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String],
>   scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char])

I also get a similar error when calling the parameterised version of createStream.

Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a long message to say that topics needs to be `Set[String]`, not `Set[Char]`.

The best way I can see to fix this is to do:

```
topic.map(_.toString).toSet
```

But, if you truly only have one topic, then just do `Set(topic)` as the above splits the string into a set of single characters.